# How do I resolve the 'array makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook' React compile warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm receiving a React compile warning *"The 'fArray' array makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 79) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the initialization of 'fArray' in its own useMemo() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"*.

I've tried using the '**useMemo**' for the array, but not sure how to do it correctly in this situation. What is the correct way? ...seems like everything I try produces errors or more warnings.

Here is what I've tried:

```
//how the array looks prior edits:
  let fArray: Stuff[] = [...stuff];

// What I've tried : 
   const fArray = useMemo(() => { return Stuff[] = [...stuff] }, []);
// BUT, this doesn't work because 'Stuff' only refers to type but is being used as value here
```

How array is being used:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    //other code here....

    dispatch(setStuff([fArray[0].id]));
    
  }, [dispatch, fArray]); //eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stuff` is a type. You are using it as a variable `Stuff[] = [...stuff]`

You can do,

```
const fArray = useMemo(() => { return [...stuff] as Stuff[] }, [stuff]);
```

or you can also do,

```
interface Stuff {
  name: string;
}
const stuff: Stuff[] = [{name: 'x'}, {name: 'y'}] // simulating typescript already knows the type of `stuff`

export default function App() {
  const fArray = useMemo(() => { return [...stuff] }, [stuff]);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    //other code here....
  }, [fArray]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: Also make sure to add `stuff` to the dep array. Otherwise React may not render what you expected to render.